# Configure the PHP built-in web server

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, webserver

While using the built-in PHP web server, how do you set configuration options, typically set using `php.ini` or a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Configuration file:

Simply add a custom configuration file to your project, and then run the built-in server with this flag:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -c php.ini
```

This is especially helpful for settings that cannot be set at runtime using `ini_set()`.

#### Example `php.ini` file:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

### Without a configuration file:

You can also forgo the `php.ini` file and add your configuration inline:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -c "short_open_tag=On" -t public/ server.php
```

Comment: Configuration inline doesn't seem to work for me in PHP 7.2